# Idle CPU and CPU Power-saving mode definitions

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

I have a presentation on CPU's and there's some stuff I want to clarify that's defined in many research papers that I'm not fully sure about.

- How can the CPU ever be idle? I mean as long as you are running the OS doesn't that mean that there is constantly some instructions that are sent to be executed? Or perhaps how are CPU idle cycles ever happening? Shouldn't the task scheduler always have a job for the CPU such as a low priority one or maybe a program that just runs when there's nothing to do?
- What does it mean physically to have the CPU enter power-save mode? Does it simply reduces the frequency at which it runs?
- How do CPU cycles work on multiple core architectures, is there a global clock for all of the cores and an internal clock within each of them which gets synchronized globally? And in the case of multi-core CPU's I assume we can have cycles truly run independently from one another and pass messages to each other if they need to?

Comment: The OS doesn't actually need to *do something* 100% of the time. I'm not sure how this works on modern CPUs, but at least around Win2000 times the OS could just start [looping an instruction like HLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT) in a very-low-priority process, to tell the CPU that it needs no calculations to be done. Someone else will expand on this.

Answer (score 0):

CPU does have different instructions and power modes for power management:   C states and P states (and many other states), and instructions like HLT.

http://ilinuxkernel.com/?p=1990

> P-States： Performance States
>
> T-States：Throttling States
>
> S-States：Sleeping States
>
> G-States：Global States
>
> C-States：CPU States

HLT will put the CPU into completely non-functioning modes, until the next interrupt (eg, timer) comes in.   If it is an inter-CPU interrupt then another CPU is trying to wake him up.

Then there is the P states and C states:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AWXt.png)

And the rule in power management is the the boot CPU (cpu0) is never powered down, only other non-boot cores:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9YAO.png)